# rails routes link_to specific controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, static-pages

For a simple quiz app I'm trying to connect a couple of static pages, but since I'm new to Ruby on Rails I'm having trouble with how to correctly define my routes.

I have a static page pages/user_quiz_start with this link that is supposed to send the user to pages/user_quiz_question.html and initialize the current_question_index variable:

```
#views/pages/user_quiz_start.html.rb:
<%= link_to 'Start Quiz!', :controller => :pages, :action => :start_quiz %>
```

But I get `"ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Pages#show"` -> `No route matches {:action=>"start_quiz", :controller=>"pages", :page=>"user_quiz_start"}`

Here is my controller and my routes:

```
#pages_controller.rb:
def show
    if valid_page?
      render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
    else
      render file: "public/404.html", status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def start_quiz
    if @quiz_session.start!
      redirect_to user_quiz_question_path, notice: 'Quiz has been started'
    else
      redirect_to :back, error: 'Quiz cannot be started'
    end
  end

#in the model quiz_session.rb:
def start!
    self.current_question_index = 0
end

#routes.rb:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  get 'home/index'
  get '/user_quiz_start', :to => redirect('pages/user_quiz_start.html')
  get '/user_quiz_question' => redirect('pages/user_quiz_question.html')

  # Setup static pages
  get "/pages/:page" => "pages#show"

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: redirect('/pages/user_home')
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end

  root 'pages#home'
end
```

I know my routes are inconsistent and I have been looking at various guides concerning routes in rails, but I just don't get it yet :/ Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Pages#show" -> No route matches {:action=>"start_quiz", :controller=>"pages", :page=>"user_quiz_start"}

**Problem:**

You don't have a route for `start_quiz` action of `pages_controller` in your **`config/routes.rb`** file

**Solution:**

Add this entry in routes.rb

```
get "/pages/start_quiz" => "pages#start_quiz"
```

And now the route will take you to the `start_quiz` action in `pages_controller`

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense :)